# arcengine isaveas2 Failed to copy raster dataset

Tags: raster, esri-arc-engine

The source code are following:
when run into the last `pSaveAs`.`SaveAs`... then the computer say "failed to copy raster `dataset`".

The source code are following:

```
private void SaveRaster(IRasterDataset2 mygeoDataset,string sFormat,string filePath,string fileName )
        {
            `ISaveAs2` pSaveAs = mygeoDataset as ISaveAs2;
            if(!pSaveAs.CanSaveAs(sFormat))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no support file type");
                return;
            }
            IWorkspaceFactory pworspaceFactory = new RasterWorkspaceFactoryClass();
            IWorkspace pWorkspace = null;
            pWorkspace = pworspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(filePath, 0);
            pSaveAs.SaveAs(fileName, pWorkspace, "GRID");
        }
```

Comment: 未处理 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HelpLink="raster.hlp"
  HResult=-2147217383
  Message=Failed to copy raster dataset
  Source="esriDataSourcesRaster.GdalDriver"
  ErrorCode=-2147217383
  StackTrace:
       在 ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISaveAs2.SaveAs(String Name, IWorkspace Workspace, String Format)
       在 SGA.SingleGA.EmguCVtest.SaveRaster(IRasterDataset2 mygeoDataset, String sFormat, String filePath, String fileName) 位置 C:\Study\travelWork\MapGenerelizationLesson\2014.7.10 建筑物移位算法（ IGA+NormalGA+ConstraintGA）\SGA.SingleGA\EmguCVtest.cs:行号 299

Comment: Edit the question, rather than add the error message in the comments. Also it is more appropriate to be in English, `未处理` -> `Unhandled exception:` etc.

Comment: this problem has solved. because the arcgis grid file type can not be named with more than 13 characteristics.